# Retrieve json value php and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I use jQuery Ajax with php,I get value in json encode in php file but I cant decode in 
result

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".upload").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = {};
            jQuery(".ajax_elements").each(function(_, elem) {
                data[this.id] = this.value;
            });
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "map.php",
                data: data,
                cache: false
            }).done(function(result) {
                alert(result);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**PHP code**

```
 echo json_encode(array('URL'=>'http://test.com'));
```

here I get {URL:http://test.com} in alert but how to get value of this URL?

I tried jQuery.parseJSON(result); but it shows error in console

Comment: Your code missing dataType: "json"

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".upload").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {};
        jQuery(".ajax_elements").each(function(_, elem) {
            data[this.id] = this.value;
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "map.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json" // add this line in your code
        }).done(function(result) {
            alert(result.URL);
        });
    });
});
```

Set `dataType:"json"` for URL alert `result.URL` in your Ajax success function .

Answer (score 0):

You parse it like this:

```
alert(result.URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

TO build on what @Leonardo answered above. When you pass to jquery the json_encoded variable it is already interpreted as an OBJECT on your javascript code. So you just reference it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse with parseJSON, use this:

```
}).done(function(result) {
     var res = $.parseJSON(result);
     alert(res.URL);
});
```

now in res you have what you're sending in JSON format from php, if you alert "res.URL" you'll get "http://test.com".
You can pass other parameters and call them using res.parameterNameFromPhp